# When(Where) + past or present?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, tense, difference, present-tense

I don't know whether to choose to use past simple or present simple after when(where).

For example:

1. I like the part where he kills the villain.
2. I like the part where he killed the villain.

1 and 2 both sound natural and seem interchangeable.

3. I like the part where he doesn't kill the villain.
4. I like the part where he didn't kill the villain.

According to the first 2 examples, 3 and 4 should have no difference but 4 sounds unnatural.

So the question is what is the difference between using past simple or present simple after when(where) in these cases and if 4 has a different meaning, then what is it?

Also

5. I like the part where he had killed the villain.

What is the difference between 5 and the other 4?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They are all fine. I like the part where he had killed the villain [before they left the city].

Answer (score 1):

This is not really about the grammar of *when* or *where*. These usually follow the normal rules for backshifting:

> I like it when you sing that song.
>
> I liked it when you sang that song.

This question is about the way we talk about stories - books, films, etc. We have the choice of talking about them in the present (as the timeless things they are) or in the past (our experience of watching or reading them).

I find all your examples equally natural, and also a third pair:

> I liked the part where he killed the villain.
>
> I liked the part where he didn't kill the villain.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am no longer confused. One more question. Is 5 the example value and when do we use it?

Comment: Also there was an sentence which says "Sorry in advance to anybody whose name I pronounce wrong". I think it should be "pronounced" rather than "pronounce" , so why is present simple used in this sentence?

Comment: Also why it is "timeless"?

Comment: Is present simple referring to the past in these sentences like it do when we tell stories?

Comment: The book, or the film, or the TV programme, exists, in the past, and the present, and the future, so it is "timeless", and we can refer to it - and our feelings for it - in the present if we wish. Our reading or watching it was in the past, so we can refer to it - and our feelings for it - in the past if we wish.

Comment: @lollel123: your question about "pronounce" should be a separate question. But I'll attempt to answer. Both are possible, depending on whether the speaker is choosing to position themselves temporally at the time of the speaking (present simple, representing either timeless or future), or at the later time when the people whose names are mispronounced are offended (past).